# How to arrange dates in a drop-down list according their natural way using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset with some dates in it. Now the dates are arranged randomly (March — Febryary — January):

```
var uniqueDates = ["2016-03-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-02-01"];
```

I need to put these dates into the drop-down list according their natural way (January — Febryary — March). Now I'm using the code below:

```
d3.select("select#dateSelector")
  .selectAll("option")
  .data(uniqueDates)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) {
    return formatRU(new Date(d));
  })
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .property("selected", function(d) {
    return i == uniqueDates.length - 1;
  });
```

How can I get the right sequence in my drop-down list like this:

```
<select id="dateSelector">
  <option value="2016-01-01">Январь 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-02-01">Февраль 2016</option>
  <option value="2016-03-01">Март 2016</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the string representations of the dates by actually converting them to a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
uniqueDates.sort(function(a, b){
    return d3.ascending(new Date(a), new Date(b));
});
```